# Only specific words separated with space

Tags: php, forms, preg-match

I'm making a notice system with tags, but only with the specifics tags separated for space
*(Example: tag1 tag2 tag3)* in the text input, how i do for verify if so. 
Is possible with preg_match or other?

The idea is if the user write in the input **"tag1 tag2"** with spaces, the form is submitted, but if no, show the error, and need rewrite.
In [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you have the parameter [tag1|tag2] but i don't understand...

Comment: just properly label your text input that the user is expected to input the criteria `tag1 tag2 tag3`, then process the input and use `explode(' ', $_POST['textbox'])`

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired result? What are tags? HTML Tags?